# SolrjPopulator error with solr 6.3

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying to run the simple solrj api example and facing the below error.Any suggestions pls.
[image]

Error:-
[image]

Comment: updating Java might help. which version of Java you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code probably you're using an old version of SolrJ.

I suggest to upgrade your SolrJ version to use the following way to create your HTTP client:

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/person";
SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
```